# 2002 Toyota Tazz slipping clutch

Tags: toyota, clutch, tazz

Does the 2002 Toyota Tazz 1.3 liter have an adjustable clutch cable? 
My clutch keeps on slipping - do I need to replace it or can I just adjust it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I only have a reference for a Corolla, which is supposed to be much like the Tazz. It shows the car to have a hydraulic clutch, which means it wouldn't be adjustable. Even if there were other things like low fluid in the reservoir, it would act in the opposite way, meaning it would be hard to shift in/out of gear with the engine running. If the clutch is slipping, most likely it will need to be replaced.